# Kurepa trees and inaccessible cardinals in $L$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

Given a regular uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ we say that a $\kappa-$tree is $\kappa-$Kurepa if it has at least $\kappa^+$ branches. If $\kappa=\omega_1$ we simply say that $T$ is Kurepa. In this respect, my question is the following:

Why the non existence of Kurepa trees implies that $\omega_2$ is an inaccessible in Gödel universe $L$?

Is someone willing to give me a proof of this fact?

Thanks!

Comment: A proof of this can be found on p.10 of [Jech's. "Trees"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2271510?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). (Note that you can gain free access to that paper by registration with JSTOR.) It uses the following Theorem by Solovay: If $V = L[X]$ for some $X \subseteq \omega_{1}$, then there is a Kurepa tree.

Comment: A proof of Solovay's Theorem can be found on p. 150 of Jech's old "Set Theory (1978)".

Comment: Sorry @Stefan but I'm not able to see the relationship between Solovay's Theorem and the inaccessibility of $\omega_2$...

Comment: @Stefan if I were able to see that there exists a set $X\subset \omega_1$ such that $\omega_1^{L[X]}=\omega_1$ and $\omega_2^{L[X]}=\omega_2$ then the exercise would be solved. Any idea?

Comment: Antoine, if $\omega_2^{L[X]}<\omega_2$ for all $X\subseteq\omega_1$, then you can show that $\omega_2$ is *not* a successor cardinal in $L$ (since then there will be some $X\subseteq\omega_1$ such that $L[X]$ computes $\omega_2$ correctly by coding the needed bijections); but then $\omega_2$ is a limit cardinal in $L$ and therefore a *regular* limit cardinal in $L$. Well, then, the proof is now complete.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, is the following proof right? If $\omega_2$ is not inaccessible in $L$ then there exists a cardinal (in $L$) $\lambda$ s.t. $(\lambda^+)^L=\omega_2$ and $|\lambda|=\omega_1$. Now take $f:\omega_1\rightarrow\lambda$ a bijection and $X$ a subset of $\omega_1$ coding it. Now, $L[X]\vDash |\lambda|=\omega_1$ and then since $\omega_2=(\lambda^+)^L\leq (\lambda^+)^{L[X]}\leq (\omega_1^+)^{L[X]}=(\omega_2)^{L[X]}$ So finally $\omega_2=(\omega_2)^{L[X]}$.

Comment: Also if $\omega_2=(\omega_2)^{L[X]}$ then $\omega_1=(\omega_1)^{L[X]}$. Indeed, if $\omega_1>(\omega_1)^{L[X]}$ then, since $\omega_1$ is a cardinal in $L[X]$ (because to be cardinal is downwards absolute) then $\omega_1\geq(\omega_1^+)^{L[X]}$ so $\omega_1\geq(\omega_2)^{L[X]}=\omega_2$. A contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, it looks okay.